# How to convert a huge database of ED50 coordinates into WGS84?

Tags: convert, wgs84

As the title says I have a huge database containing (among other data) a pair of coordinates using ED50 standard for each record.

I'm tasked to update the whole thing and convert all the ED50 entries to WGS84.
The whole database is used in FileMaker, I can export it in csv,xls,tab and some other formats.

Is there a "function" that I can apply to all these fields and change them all at once?

I searched on the internet but have found nothing useful.

Comment: What did you search for?  This was the first result from google when I searched:  http://tool-online.com/en/coordinate-converter.php

Comment: Export to CSV and use GDAL/OGR.

Comment: Are the coordinates contained within one country or multiple countries? That will affect whether you can do the whole lot at once or whether you should split it up into groups to take advantage of local transformations.

Comment: @BradHards I think your comment is worth expanding as a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like FileMaker (which I know nothing about) is capable of implementing coordinate conversion functions:

https://community.filemaker.com/thread/64899

but you'll have to find the equations and implement that yourself.

Alternatively, export to a spatial database (PostGIS - free, open source) or a GIS (QGIS - free, open source) do the conversion (plenty of help online), export from there, load back into FileMaker.